# How to make a client, download the file from the original location?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7, network-protocols

Let us suppose there are two nodes.

Node-1 has I.P = `100.100.100.1`

Node-2 has an I.P = `100.100.100.2`

Node-2 has a file named `foo.mp3` and is running a server. Let us say , Tomcat. `Node-1` is looking for the file `foo.mp3` and comes to know that `node-2` has it some where on its hard drive. Suppose path to `foo.mp3` on `node-2` is `E:/foo/foo.mp3`. `Node-2` can simply copy `foo.mp3` in his `webapps` folder of `tomcat` and make a link like :

```
<a href="./foo.mp3">Click to download</a>
```

But is there any way,he can escape from this responsibility of copying the file ? Isn't there a way so that he can just give a path to the file where it has been there for so long ! Like :

```
<a href="E:/foo/foo.mp3">Click to download</a>
```

Because this won't work unless `node-1` and `node-2` are the same !

Comment: You seem to have a problem about sharing files between two or more applications. Why don't you put the files in some location that both applications have access to?

Answer (score 0):

If Node-1 knows where the file is located on Node-2, why wouldn't Node-1 just point the link to Node-2, as follows:

```
<a href="http://100.100.100.2/foo/foo.mp3">Click to download</a>
```